# Bootstrap dropdown hover transition

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a fade in transition on my Bootstrap dropdown menu on hover. So far I have tried the following with no luck.

**My attempt**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition:    all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 1000ms ease;
    transition:         all 1000ms ease;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This didn't work. It delayed it by 1000ms, but didn't add any transition. I have also tried with jQuery, but without any luck aswell.

[Here's a fiddle with the code](https://jsfiddle.net/52hgLprm/1/) - The dropdown menu is on the first link "Arla nu" in the menu.

Comment: conflict with the bootstrap properties

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-transition:    all 1000ms ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 1000ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 1000ms ease;
    transition:         all 1000ms ease;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Add the js function too

```
$(function(){
  var $menu = $('.dropdown-menu');

  $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(
    function() {
      $menu.css('opacity',1);
    },
    function() {
      $menu.css('opacity',0);
    });
})();
```

Will update the answer with JSfiddle

**Update**

Check Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pjej7o2m/296/

Comment: Same problem, it delays in by 1000ms, but doesn't add the animation. Would be great with a fiddle, if you got it to work.

Comment: After your update I can see it works on your example with a standard bootstrap dropdown. My setup is a bit different, as you can see in my fiddle, and your solution doesn't apply to mine. The click to open doesn't work in your example either.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have just left off telling what to transition.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
  opacity: 0;
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover .dropdown-menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Same problem, it delays in by 1000ms, but doesn't add the animation.

Comment: It looks like you are also using bootstrap? If so double check that bootstrap is not adding a class on hover such as "open". That may be overriding things you are trying to accomplish. You may need to strengthen your declarations a bit.